# Anonymous access does not work for  Site Collection Images

Tags: publishing-site, anonymous-authentication

I am trying to give anonymous access to Site Collection Images. I followed http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/rodneyguzman/archive/2007/08/30/21200.aspx but it does not work (keeps asking for username and pwd).

It works like charm for new doc libraries and lists.

I am using publishing site template so followed this (just in case) http://www.petestilgoe.com/2010/02/allowed-anonymous-access-on-a-sharepoint-list-and-still-get-prompted-for-a-login/

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that all components used to build the page are not only checked in but published too.  This applies for anything that might be in process, such as Site Collection Images, Master pages, Page Layouts, items in the Style Library and even the Page itself.  If any one of these has no published version, it will prompt for credentials when accessed anonymously.

Digging around in your 12/logs or 14/logs may also provide some clues as what the specific cause of the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the items in the site collection images library are not checked in?  I'm not certain this would cause it, but if they've been added by an admin and not yet checked in perhaps an anonymous user would be denied access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Please go to your IIS -> your domain -> expand the domain and look for the _layouts folder.
2. Please copy the PHYSICAL PATH to this _layouts folder.
3. Once this is done, please delete _layouts folder from the IIS and re-add it back with the same PHYSICAL PATH. I am 100% sure you will get rid of the problems.

I initially have the same problems with my Sharepoint site and the staff at [asphostcentral.com](http://www.asphostcentral.com/Windows-Sharepoint-2010-Hosting.aspx) just informed me the steps mentioned above. Hope this works for you.

Comment: This seems awkward. Do you have a reference to this bug?